# View e-mails in transposed/“wide format”/left to right rather than top-down “long-format”?

Tags: email, formatting

How to reshape email view into transposed/wide-format (left to right) rather than the default top down long-format?

Comment: We cannot see over your shoulder to know what you require. You need to tell us. Basic details such as what OS, what mail client… usually all that's needed is to drag the window to whatever shape you prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The majority of email is composed in HTML and uses tables to define the message structure.

In most cases, simply making the screen wider will "resize" the content as you create it,.

However, the recipient will have their own window size which will flow most emails into a layout appropriate for their screen and preferences.

To force the recipient to see it wide as you intend you would need to actually edit the HTML code itself to define the desired width of the message. This, however, will make it difficult for more people to read your email so don't do it unless you have a truly compelling reason.